# CakePHP lazy loading fails with static access to class constants

Tags: cakephp, static, lazy-loading

In a CakePHP 2.2 app, I'm using class constants in a Model for some internal configuration. The following issue came up.

#### Short version:

Cake's lazy class loading will not be triggered by a static call to the Model class.

If the first access to a Model in a Controller is

```
MyModel::SOME_CONST // fails
```

the class will be unknown. If any instance of the class is used before, it's fine:

```
$this->MyModel->something();
MyModel::SOME_CONST // works
```

Not knowing about the details of the lazy loading implementation:

**Question**: Is this something that is impossible to fix? If so, why? How do I then best work around it in my App myself (wrap consts in a function)? Or is there a chance to improve the lazy loading so that it works with static access, too?

#### Long version with code:

In order to test the different cases, I made a small test App with 1 Model and 1 Controller:

Model/Post.php:

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = false; // Don't bother with a DB

    const FOO = "foo";

    public $bar = "bar";
}
```

Controller/PostsController.php:

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public function constant() {
        debug(Post::FOO);
    }

    public function variable() {
        debug($this->Post->bar);
    }

    public function variableFirst() {
        debug($this->Post->bar);

        debug(Post::FOO);
    }
}
```

Accessing the three controller actions through the browser, the different cases can now be tested.

1) accessing the Model constant (at `/posts/constant`):

> Error: Class 'AppModel' not found

2) accessing the Model variable (at `/posts/variable`):

> 'bar'

3) accessing the Model constant AFTER a variable (at `/posts/variable`):

> 'bar'
>
> 'foo'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lazyloading works with normal class calls as well as static calls IF you correctly approach it.

Correctly means, that you always have to App::uses() all used classes at the top of your file

for AppModel in a model file:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Post extends AppModel {}
```

see the core files for details.

Comment: Nice. I was just relying on the Controller automagically loading its Model. But an explicit `App::uses()` is no problem. Thanks!

Comment: That isn't working for me. I had to add App::uses('Post', 'Model') to the top of my CONTROLLER. It's not entirely clearly why either of these are necessary to access class constants.

Comment: Exactly. If you use your Post model in a non-framework-dynamic way (not via ClassRegistry, loadModel, etc) you need to manually assert that your model is available - thus the App::uses('Post', 'Model') statement.

Comment: *non-framework-dynamic* is a nice way to say *CakePHP breaks native OOP*. If you realize this, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches asking *why*.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary You are totally misinterpreting the meaning of this sentence. Framework dynamics and OOP doesn't necessarily have anything to do with each other.